# Which data structure and/or algorithm is suitable for this problem?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have a 30MB .txt file containing random strings like:

```
416
abcd23
cd542
banana
bambam
```

There is 1 word per line, words are separated by a new line

I need to search the file for my chosen substring and return every matched string in the file. To make it clearer:

```
Input: cd
```

```
Output: abcd23, cd542
```

Are Generalized suffix trees, suffix trees or suffix arrays suitable for this kind of problem or is there something faster? (time complexity is important)

p.s. my programming skills are a bit sketchy so any kind of example would be kindly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @RaviSaroch Iterating through every string in the file... ^^

Comment: @gelonida 1 word per line separated by new line

Comment: is file appended? or file is not going to change?

Comment: There's this program called grep . . .

Comment: @SrikanthHugar Insertions and deletions will be performed as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are finding the strings in the file which contain one string, then the fastest method is simply to iterate through the file and check string function 'in' or 'find' on each line as follows.

```
def find_matches(filename, txt):
     with open(filename, 'r') as f:
         return [line for line in f if txt in line] # using 'in'
```

Example Usage:

```
matches = find_matches('myfile.txt', 'cd')
```

Simply reading the file avoids the overhead of structuring the fields of other methods such as Pandas -- [Pandas one of the slower methods](https://medium.com/casual-inference/the-most-time-efficient-ways-to-import-csv-data-in-python-cc159b44063d) of reading in a file.  Also: [What is the fastest way to search a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58876624/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-search-the-csv-file/58883518#58883518).

String methods using in, or find basically rely on an optimized [fastsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26008904/python-cost-of-find-function) that's implemented in C whose efficiency per string search is:

> It looks like the implementation is in worst case O(N*M) (The same as
>   a naive approach), but can do O(N/M) in some cases (where N and M are
>   the lengths of the string and substring respectively), and O(N) in
>   frequent cases

Comment: I fixed above solution (I hope)
Please also note, that above solution only works if there is only one word per line.

Please indicate if you mgiht have mutliple words per line.