# Efficiently read in large csv files using pandas or dask in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, memory, dask

I want to read in large csv files into python in the fastest way possible. I have a csv file of ~100 million rows. I came across this primer https://medium.com/casual-inference/the-most-time-efficient-ways-to-import-csv-data-in-python-cc159b44063d and they go through a few packages

1. csv
2. pandas
3. dask
4. datatable
5. paratext

For my purposes, "csv" is too raw and I want to leverage the type inference included in the other packages. I need it to work on both windows and linux machines and have also looked into datatable and paratext, but have had problems installing right package dependencies (neither are on the anaconda package repo). So that leaves pandas and dask. At first glance, dask seems much faster, but I only realized that it only does the computations if you call ".compute"

My specific use case is that even though the raw csv file is 100+ million rows, I only need a subset of it loaded into memory. For example, all rows with date >= T. Is there a more efficient way of doing this than just the below example? Both pandas and dask take similar time.

**EDIT: The csv file updates daily and there is no pre-known order of the rows of the file. Ie it is not necessarily the case that the most recent dates are at the end of the file**

```
import pandas as pd
import dask as dd
from datetime import datetime

s = datetime.now()
data1 = pd.read_csv("test.csv", parse_dates=["DATE"])
data1 = data1[data1.DATE>=datetime(2019,12,24)]
print(datetime.now()-s)

s = datetime.now()
data2 = dd.read_csv("test.csv", parse_dates=["DATE"])
data2 = data2[data2.DATE>=datetime(2019,12,24)].compute()
print(datetime.now()-s)
```

Comment: Are the dates in the .csv file in order, or are they in random order?  If they are in order, then you can seek to the date range you're interested in and start reading from there.   If they are in random order, then it would be fastest to do a one-time pass of the .csv and recreate it with the dates in order.  Alternatively you can create an index with date/seek location.

Comment: Dates are not in order, will edit post to include this detail. Also, the file will update daily (not necessarily in order) so the one time pass doesn't work

Comment: If the file is created once per day, but you read several times per day I might have some ideas. If you read only once per day but you know, that a new csv file is the same than the previous csv file with lines only added at the end of the file, there's also something you might be able to do.
 (Some ideas can be seen here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58876624/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-search-the-csv-file/58877382#58877382 ) 
If none of the above is true I think you can't optimize a lot.

CSV is just not a great file format for filtering, as there's no index or other helpers

Answer (score 2):

Your Dask solution looks good to me.  For parsing CSV in particular you might want to use Dask's multiprocessing scheduler.  Most Pandas operations are better with threads, but text-based processing like CSV, is an exception.

```
data2 = data2[data2.DATE>=datetime(2019,12,24)].compute(scheduler="processes")
```

See https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/scheduling.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of columns in your CSV, it might be more efficient to first read only the date column (pd.read_csv has a "usecols" field), then use that to determine what rows contain the data that you want, then use the "skiprows" field to skip all the other rows that you don't need and this time actually read all the columns from the CSV. Parsing all the columns in pandas or any other derivative of it can take a long time and use a ton of memory, so avoiding reading a ton of data that you will never actually use will save a lot of time.

Answer (score -1):

CSV is not an efficient file format for filtering, CSV files don't have indexes for data fields, don't have key based access. For each filter operation you always have to read all lines.

You can improve the performance marginally by using a library that's written in C or is doing some stuff a little smarter than another library, but don't expect miracles/ I'd expect an improvement of a few percent to perhaps 3x if you identify/implement an optimized C version reading your lines and performing the initial filtering.

If you read the CSV file more often then it might be useful to convert the file during the first read (multiple options exist: hand craftet helpers, indexes, sorting, data bases, ...)
and perform subsequent reads on the 'data base'.

If you know that the new CSV file is a the same as the previous version plus lines appended to the end of the file, you had to memorize the position of the last line of the previous version and just add the new lines to your optimized data file. (data base, ...)

Other file formats might be hundreds or thousand times more efficient, but creating these files the first time is probably at least as expensive as your searching (so if reading only once, there's nothing you can optimize)

If none of above conditions is true you cannot expect a huge performance increase

You might look at [What is the fastest way to search the csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58876624/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-search-the-csv-file/58877382#58877382)

for accelerations (assuming files can be sorted/indexed by a search / filter criteria)

Comment: CSV file changes once a day, I need to read it once a day. Reading in by chunks does not improve time. I checked using both read csv methods

Comment: rewrote my answer